# how to set i18n in strtus 2 automatically from DB when page loaded

Tags: internationalization

i have created a dropdown with locale type as english , franch etc and save button. when i am saving dropdown value is saved in database.. i also have creatd method who getting data from database and store in a variable ..

my requirment is when i open any page after login then based on user locale its automatically set locale..

jsp:

```
<s:select label="Select Default Language"
                                headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Default Language"    
                                list="#{'en':'English', 'fr':'France'}"
                                name="user.requestLocale"
                                value="%{user.requestLocale}" />
                                </div>
```

//save button...getter setter working fine..

// i am getting locale value in js

```
var userLocalte = "<s:property value="%{requestLocale}"/>"; //en or fr
```

//how to change locale..
// i am using this which is going infinite loop

```
// window.location.href='<c:url value="?request_locale=fr"/>';
```

//strtus.xml

```
/*<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
                <param name="i18n.parameterName">user.requestLocale</param>
            </interceptor-ref> */
```

//this is working fine with click of link.. but i want it automatically update

```
 <s:url id="url" action="reloadupdate">
    <s:param name="request_locale">%{locale.requestLocale}</s:param>
    </s:url>
    <s:a href="%{url}">Default Locale</s:a>
```

//one more method i have tired but its valid in that page only

```
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
```

//below code also not working for all page

```
 sessionMap.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, "fr");
 sessionMap.put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", "fr");
```

Answer (score 1):

got solution .

```
//en= ISO-639 Language Codes
//US=ISO-3166 Country Codes

 String userLocale="en_US"; // this data is get from db , for french fr_FR
                String userLanguage = userLocale.substring(0, 2);
                String userCountry = userLocale.substring(3, 5);
                Locale locale = new Locale(userLanguage,userCountry);
                ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale);
                sessionMap.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
```